# Can't log in on Unity: Sorry, this link is no longer valid

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I am having a problem when trying to log in on Unity Hub and https://id.unity.com/, searching for a solution I try allowing Unity througth firewall and changing my network to private (it was already in private but I try changing it to public and then private again), none of this solutions worked for me. The only "solution" I found was connecting to my phone network, what is wrong with my home network? Here is a screenshot of the error message.
[image]

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue on my house network.

In all the machines that I connect I receive this error.

- No matter if I connect using WIFI or Ethernet (Using cable).
- No matter if I try to log in on a web browser or on the Unity Hub.
- Always the same.

The solution that I found was to use the 4G internet of my Android device on my Laptop, creating a "Mobile Hotspot" (Wifi Point on your Android device) and connect your computer to that Wifi network:

[image]

(Disable the Wifi on you Android device, and enable Data Usage -> Mobile Data), make sure you purchased an internet packet for your Android device, or you have montly internet plan.

- Another solution could be just to connect using another Wifi network, for example a network from a Shopping Mall.

The problem is something related to the network configuration, so the fastest solution is to use another network just to log in into your Unity account, and then use your network for the rest (Keep your session active as long as possible to avoid doing this again and again).

Comment: Switching to cell phone network doesn't work for me. Did all the other things too. Restart, cookie clears, everything. I suspect it only clears up with time - when it's forgotten about the old IP address, or something.

Comment: You should not use the same wifi network on your phone (disable wifi), you should have your own mobile internet packet 4G internet, this worked at least for me.